# Some of the ASan option of LLVM Clang is not available while targeting risc-v

Tags: clang, llvm, gnu, riscv

I'm observing the exact execution of the Address Sanitizer supported by LLVM. To do so, I was compiling some test codes with the option argument `-fsanitize`, just like `-fsanitize=address`, `-fsanitize=undefined`, etc.
This worked fine in typical target environment, such as x86, MIPS, etc. But when I tried to compile the code with GNU RISC-V toolchain(riscv64-unknown-elf) the option except `-fsanitize=undefined` led the compilation to a failure.

[Captured Bash Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzFZk.png)
This is one of the example: I tried to adapt the general ASan with the exact riscv64 toolchain and compile the assembly code file, but clang failed to compile the whole code.

Almost every document related to this function does not have enough direct information about this, so I cannot sure that this is a normal result. I'm expecting there's no corresponding options with the general Address Sanitizer function in GNU risc-v toolchain(except the UBSan), but still not sure about this. Is it correct the clang does not support the ASan options other than the undefined behavior sanitizer? Or am I doing something wrong?